# AttributeError: "tuple" object has no attribute "split"

Tags: python, list, object, tuples, attributeerror

im new to python and im having a bit of difficulty with a beginner question

```
Write a Python program which accepts a sequence of comma-separated numbers from user and generate a list and a tuple with those numbers
```

and this is the code i wrote

```
sea =  9 , 8 , 8 , 8

list = sea.split(",")
tuple = tuple(list)

print ("List: " ,list)
print ("Tuple: " ,tuple)
```

but its giving me an Attribute Error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

thats it hehe, thank you for taking time for reading this, please help me correct it :0

Comment: Just so you know, `sea` is already a `tuple`.

Answer (score 4):

Now, the `sea` variable holds a tuple of `(9, 8, 8, 8)`.

To accept input from user, use `input()` function. The `input()` function returns a string. so you can use `str.split(',')` to split it.

Also, don't use `list` or `tuple` for variable names, you're shadowing the built-in functions.

The full code:

```py
input_from_user = input()

l = [int(n) for n in input_from_user.split(",")]
t = tuple(l)

print("List: ", l)
print("Tuple: ", t)
```

Output (for example):

```
1,2,3,4
List:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Tuple:  (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: tysm for the answer now i get it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap content of the `sea` varible with `"`. 
Your error happends because `9 , 8 , 8 , 8` is not a string by default. It is, as error says, tuple. By wrapping it like this `"9 , 8 , 8 , 8"` it will become string and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `sea = 9,8,8,8` it becomes `sea = (9,8,8,8)`. It's a **Tuple.**

Try this Code

```
SEA = "9,8,8,8"
LIST = [int(x) for x in SEA.split(",")]
TUPLE = tuple(LIST) #Directly Convert List as a Tuple
print("List",LIST)
print("Tuple",TUPLE)
```

> NOTE: Don't use reserved words as variables

Answer (score 0):

Python interprets objects separated by commas as a tuple. If you were to print the type of `sea`, you'd get `tuple`.

The `.split()` function is for [str objects](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). It's not applicable for tuples.

Also, based on the prompt you were given, you should be using `sea =`[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) instead of defining the numbers. This will allow the person running the program to choose the numbers.

Additionally, try not to use variable names like `list` or `tuple` or a name that could override the built-in functions. This can cause some unwanted errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as following.

```
sea =1,2,3,4

list1 =list(sea)
tuple1 =sea

print ("List: " ,list1)
print ("Tuple: " ,tuple1)
```

Don't use keywords as variable names, it may confuse the interpreter
It is storing the values by default in tuple

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this to you,
The way in which you are taking the input

> sea =  9 , 8 , 8 , 8

The value in the **sea** variable becomes **tuple**.

Later when you apply this function,

> list = sea.split(",")

It will throw an error, due the reason that **tuple** do not have **split** function, **string** has this built-in function

If you want **user input** you can take input in this way which is going to accept a string:

```
sea = input()
```

Or if you want **hard coded values** you can use double quotes or single quotes around them to make them string:

```
sea =  "9 , 8 , 8 , 8"
```

So your code should look like this :

```
sea =  input()

l_list = sea.split(",")
t_tuple = tuple(l_list)

print ("List: " ,l_list)
print ("Tuple: " ,t_tuple)
```

Also do not use **reserved words** and **built-in** function names as variables otherwise they will override the built-in functions and keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to take a string input.

```
sea = input('Enter: ')
list = sea.split(",")
tuple = tuple(list)

print ("List: " ,list)
print ("Tuple: " ,tuple)
```

This wont work

```
sea =  9 , 8 , 8 , 8
```